# UML-Association in C#, keeping consistent linking

Tags: c#, uml, associations

I am trying to create a set of C# classes, which share links among each other. In UML speak, these are associations, and they are mostly bi-directional.

Usually, code for the 1:n association would look like this:

```
public class A
{
    internal List<B> linked_items_of_B;
}

public class B
{
    internal A groupnode_A;
}
```

Now, I'd need some special functions for setting/clearing the links. I want to insure that the links are always mutually correct. So if an A item points to a B, that B item shall also point back to A. And removing the association in B shall also remove the list entry on A.

I am looking for a way to create these links (maybe with code generated from a UML tool) so I can easily assign/unassign associations and the framework somehow helps me holding the links consistent.

Does C# have such a feature or do I need to build this myself with some attributes or generated accessor code?

Comment: For class B it's simply making `groupnode_A` a property (which in general you should prefer over fields), which when set/changed removes itself from the list in old A and add itself to the list in new A. For the list in class A, I think you would need a wrapper list which encapsulates the actual list and handles the cases when items are changed using the Add and Remove methods.

Comment: Navigation properties are usually taken care of by the ORM. This seems all too academic. Are you in a academic setting?

Comment: No, I am not in a academic setting, but with a glowing, larger number of classes I start getting problems with this.

Comment: Generating properties for each AssociationEnd would be a way, but seems ugly to me. I wanted to know if there is an elegant way I missed. I have the feeling it might be a common proglem when translating UML class diagrams and working with the associatons a lot.

Comment: Ever since I left Uni (12+ years) I haven't met anyone working with UML, tbh. (Apart from reading some Pattern-Descriptions)

Comment: @Fildor You shouldn't have moved to the jungle. UML is used in large organizations. Companies working for the bin prefer to just code and throw the results away once done. Makes pretty much sense. Btw.: I graduated more than 30 yrs. ago.

Comment: @Blindleistung I have little experience with C#, but for the UML part you would just use constraints to express what you need.

Comment: @qwerty_so Yes, large Orgs tend to be helplessly inefficient. I was in small to medium businesses, where using UML would have lead to instant miss of deadlines.

Comment: It is very interesting to see the comments about UML. Basically, I tried to use the UML Association to describe the bidirectional Link I want to have between classes. The the Association describes it best. Of course, the class diagram is the only part of UML which is somewhat useful. The other diagram types are completely useless.

Comment: I guess I will go with marking the links with attributes, and create a python script which grinds these, and creates a seperate file with partial class adding all the property setters where I don't see them. Also code generation, but not from UML but the source.